# UnboundLocalError : search bar

Tags: python, django

I try to set up a search bar, when I put a good code on the search bar, I have the product which is displayed but if it does not find the product I have an error so I put a message if it can't find the product.
errore message (**UnboundLocalError: local variable 'product' referenced before assignment**)
And the error comes at the level of the line which contains the context (context={'article':product} )

Views.py

```
@login_required
def search(request):
  code=request.GET.get('search')
  url='http://myAPI/Product/GetProduct'
  x=requests.post(url)
  contenu=x.json()
  all_products=contenu['products']
  selected_produit= next((item for item in all_products if item['code']== code),None)
  if selected_produit != None:
    product=selected_produit
  else:
    messages.error(request,'Article not found.')

  context={'article':product}
  return render(request,'panier/search.html',context)
```

search.html

```
  {% if messages %}
      {% for message in messages %}
        <p {% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</p>
      {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
  
  {{article.code}}
  {{article.name}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error explains what's wrong. If `selected_product` is `None`, then `product` is never assigned a value. Give it a value in the `else` branch, or simply use `selected_product` directly since there doesn't seem to be any other use for the variable `product`.